# Insert element in Array (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, insert

I need to insert a 0 in my array after the `if` condition is right.

Here is my attempt:

```
for i=1:length(HPred)
    if HPred(i) ~= HPired(i)            
        if HPred(i) - HPired(i) > 5         
            HPred(i) = [HPred(i) 0 ]; % Here is the problem
            i=i+1;            
        elseif HPred(i) - HPired(i) < -5 
            HPired(i) = [HPired(i) 0]; %also
            i=i+1;
        end
    end
end
```

The error Code is:

> In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.
>   
> Error in Einlesen (line 167) HPired(i) = [HPired(i) 0];

Can someone help me?

Comment: Aside: Why are you doing `i=i+1` within a for loop? This has no effect on anything in this context and can be removed, since `i` is automatically incremented by the definition of a `for` loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert like so:

```
HPred = [HPred(1:i) 0 HPred(i+1:end)];
```

As you write and the gotten error body, it does not meaningful in syntax.
Also you can define an inline function using `cat` (to concatenate matrices) as mentioned [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/48942-insert-element-in-vector):

```
insert = @(a, x, n)cat(2,  x(1:n), a, x(n+1:end));
insert(3, [1,2,4,5], 2)
```

> ans = 1     2     3     4     5

And you can use it for your case:

```
HPred = insert(0, HPred, i);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. When i implement this example my 0 is inserted 1 element to late. I will look up how to use the cat function and maybe fix it by myself. Thank you very much for your effort !

Comment: To insert one element sooner, just use `HPred = [HPred(1:i-1) 0 HPred(i:end)];`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you wanted to insert zeros by conditions, here is a fully vectorised version. The input vectors may not contain any NaN's and have to be row vectors (format 1xN). The `HPred(i) ~= HPired(i)`condition is superfluous since the later conditions can only be true if this one is true too.

```
% some random data
HPired = randi(20,1,10); 
HPred = randi(20,1,10); 

% temp variable for the indexes
temp = nan(size(HPred));
% indexes that fulfil condition = 0
temp(HPred - HPired>5) = 0;
% concatenate vertically
temp=[HPred; temp];

% same as before for other variable
temp2 = nan(size(HPired));
temp2(HPred - HPired<-5) = 0;
temp2=[HPired; temp2];

% merge temp rows which are not NaN in a zig-zag pattern.    
HPred=temp(~isnan(temp)).';
HPired=temp2(~isnan(temp2)).';
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your whole loop could be replaced with the following, using MATLAB's vectorisation:

```
HPired = rand(100, 1);      % Your data
HPred = ones(size(HPired)); % array of ones of same size, or other data same size

% This replaces your ENTIRE loop and both if statements!
HPred(HPred ~= HPired & abs(HPred - HPired) > 5) = 0;
```

---

Your actual error is being caused by trying to assign two elements (`[HPired(i) 0]`) to one element of an array (`HPired(i)`).

Comment: Maybe i misunderstand the question, but i think the OP wants to have an additional zero after each element where the conditions are met, and not replace them  with a zero?

Comment: You're perhaps correct, there's room for misunderstanding between the too-similar variable names, lack of description for the desired behaviour, and invalid Matlab syntax... The accepted answer inserts a 0 at the `i`th element of `HPred`, which is what I aimed to reproduce. For instance it's unclear if the second `if` which changes `HPired` instead is intentional or a typo, maybe @Exix can clarify things.

Comment: I agree that it isn't a clear question, but the accepted answer returns a vector which is *longer* than the original vector, while the length of your vector stays the same. But could be that thats what he actually wants.

Comment: Ah yes you're correct, I was making the assumption on the potential desired end result. If I'm correct, it's a far neater and more MATLAB-esque way of doing it, if not I've at least included the note about the cause of the error :)

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description. I want as @LeanderMoesinger said, an additional zero after each element. So the vector gets longer.